# Adivina un grupo de caracteres de las operaciones XOR y AND a nivel de bits con sus contrapartes

Tags: c, criptografía, fgets, ingeniería-inversa

Tengo un puzzle en C que utiliza XOR. Necesito encontrar los valores de las variables locales. Todas ellas están codificadas en ebytes excepto `local_11` y `local_21` que son char

Aqui es el archivo:

```
int difficult_part(void)

{
  int iVar1;
  size_t sVar2;
  byte local_28;
  byte local_27;
  byte local_26;
  byte local_25;
  byte local_24;
  byte local_23;
  byte local_22;
  char local_21;
  byte local_18;
  byte local_17;
  byte local_16;
  byte local_15;
  byte local_14;
  byte local_13;
  byte local_12;
  char local_11;
  
  puts("guess the first eight characters.");
  fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
  sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
  if (sVar2 == 9) {
    if (((((local_18 == 0x65) && (local_17 == 0x37)) && (local_16 == 0x35)) &&
        ((local_15 == 0x35 && (local_14 == 0x32)))) &&
       ((local_13 == 99 && ((local_12 == 0x66 && (local_11 == '6')))))) {
      puts("Well done, you can try to guess the next eight characters but it won\'t be so easy.");
      fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
      sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
      if (sVar2 == 9) {
        if ((((((int)(char)local_18 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x34) &&
             (((int)(char)local_17 & 0x7fffffffU) == 99)) &&
            (((int)(char)local_16 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) &&
           (((((int)(char)local_15 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x32 &&
             (((int)(char)local_14 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) &&
            ((((int)(char)local_13 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x35 &&
             ((((int)(char)local_12 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x61 && (((int)local_11 & 0x7fffffffU) == 100)
              ))))))) {
          puts("I see you\'ve got some skills in reversing, but can you guess the next eight ?");
          fgets((char *)&local_18,0x10,stdin);
          sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_18);
          if (sVar2 == 9) {
            if ((((((int)(char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30) &&
                 (((int)(char)local_17 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x62)) &&
                (((int)(char)local_16 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x62)) &&
               (((((int)(char)local_15 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30 &&
                 (((int)(char)local_14 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x39)) &&
                ((((int)(char)local_13 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x35 &&
                 ((((int)(char)local_12 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x34 &&
                  (((int)local_11 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x66)))))))) {
              puts(
                  "I must say that I\'m impressed but it\'s not over. Will you be able to guess the next eight characters ?"
                  );
              fgets((char *)&local_28,0x10,stdin);
              sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_28);
              if (sVar2 == 9) {
                if ((((((local_28 ^ local_18) == 1) && ((local_27 ^ local_17) == 0x54)) &&
                     ((local_26 ^ local_16) == 0x55)) &&
                    (((local_25 ^ local_15) == 0x51 && ((local_24 ^ local_14) == 9)))) &&
                   (((local_23 ^ local_13) == 7 &&
                    (((local_22 ^ local_12) == 0x57 && (local_11 == local_21)))))) {
                  puts("Alright, now let\'s go to the most difficult part of this challenge.");
                  most_difficult_part();
                  iVar1 = 0;
                }
                else {
                  iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess");
                }
              }
              else {
                iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
              }
            }
            else {
              iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
            }
          }
          else {
            iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
          }
        }
        else {
          iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
        }
      }
      else {
        iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
      }
    }
    else {
      iVar1 = puts("Wrong guess.");
    }
  }
  else {
    iVar1 = puts("Well it seems that someone has trouble counting to eight.");
  }
  return iVar1;
}
```

Entonces, por esta parte:

```
(((((local_18 == 0x65) && (local_17 == 0x37)) && (local_16 == 0x35)) &&
        ((local_15 == 0x35 && (local_14 == 0x32)))) &&
       ((local_13 == 99 && ((local_12 == 0x66 && (local_11 == '6'))))))
```

Sé que:

- `local_18` = e
- `local_17` = 7
- `local_16` = 5
- `local_15` = 5
- `local_14` = 2
- `local_13` = c (99 is the decimal representation of d)
- `local_12` = f
- `local_11` = 6

Pero por la siguiente:

```
((((((int)(char)local_18 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x34) &&
             (((int)(char)local_17 & 0x7fffffffU) == 99)) &&
            (((int)(char)local_16 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) &&
           (((((int)(char)local_15 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x32 &&
             (((int)(char)local_14 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x65)) &&
            ((((int)(char)local_13 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x35 &&
             ((((int)(char)local_12 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x61 && (((int)local_11 & 0x7fffffffU) == 100)
              )))))))
```

Solo se que `((int)(char)local_12 & 0x7fffffffU) == 0x61` utilisa el bitwise AND. Pero no se lo que es `0x7fffffffU`.

Comment: `0x7fffffffU` es hexadecimal, exceptuando por la U, donde la U indica que se trata de un número unsigned. El número entonces sería 2147483647 y sería int unsigned

Comment: Muchas gracias @Eduardo Y sabes como funciona el & (AND) entre un hexadecimal y este otro ?

Comment: Es por decir, sabiendo que quiero `local_18` &, ¿cómo paso `0x1fffffffU` a la derecha de la ecuación `((int)(char)local_18 & 0x1fffffffU) == 0x30)`para obtener `local_18`

Comment: No se puede, pues en teoría te darían infinitas soluciones, en práctica te daría n respuestas, donde n son todas las posibles combinaciones de acuerdo al límite del tamaño de tu variable

Answer (score 0):

La primera duda que presentas es qué significa `0x1fffffffU`

El prefijo `0x` nos indica que es hexadecimal.
El sufijo `U` nos indica que es un entero sin signo.

> Hay otros sufijos por ejemplo `L` y `F` (long y float respectivamente)

La segunda duda que presentas es qué significa `&`

Bueno, estos operadores se conocen como operadores bitwise y trabajan a nivel de bit.

La computadora representa todo mediante 0's y 1's y nosotros podemos hacer operaciones lógicas con ellos.

El operador [bitwise AND][1] `&` funciona de esta manera.

Supongamos dos números representados de la siguiente forma

```
11010101U = 213

01101001U = 105
```

Si nosotros aplicamos el operador & sus bits van a hacer la operación lógica AND en cada bit.

```
   11010101
&  01101001
   ---------
   01000001
```

Nos fijamos que:

- 0 & 1 = 0
- 1 & 1 = 1
- 1 & 0 = 0

Tenemos que `local_18` = 0x0000000e

Podemos aplicar la operación bitwise sobre un hexadecimal cambiándolo a binario:

```
 0x1fffffffU -> 00011111111111111111111111111111
 0x0000000eU -> 00000000000000000000000000001110
```

Si hacemos la operación bitwise AND tenemos que:

```
0x1fffffffU & 0x0000000eU = 00000000000000000000000000001110

0x1fffffffU & 0x0000000eU = 0x0000000eU
```

Si lo probamos En JS tenemos que es falsa esa comparación

```js
const local_18 = 0xe;
console.log(local_18);
console.log(local_18 & 0x1fffffff);
console.log(!!(local_18 & 0x1fffffff === 0x30));
```